# Custom output buffer for CGI program, operator overloading

Tags: c++, cgi

I'm working on a CGI application, which needs to send response headers, including Content-Length, before the body, but of course this is unknown until the body is fully formed. I could just use a string and concatenate as I go, but I like using the << operator as with `cout`, so I created this little class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class outbuf {
    public:
        void operator<<(const char *str) {
            this->buffer+= str;
        }

        void operator<<(const string &str) {
            this->buffer+= str;
        }

        void obsend() {
            cout << this->buffer;
            this->buffer.clear();
        }

    private:
        string buffer;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp) {
    outbuf cbout;
    string s = " of the output buffer.";

    cbout << "This is ";
    cbout << "a test" << " ...";
    cbout << s;

    cbout.obsend();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem comes with `cbout << "a test" << " ...";` On the second operator, the compiler complains `invalid operands of types 'void' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator<<'` I understand the error, but not sure what to do about it. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? [This article](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf) looked promising, but I'm not able to understand some of what he's talking about, and it doesn't appear to exactly fit what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator<<` overload should simply return a reference to itself:

```
outbuf &operator<<(const char *str) {

// ...

    return *this;
}
```

So now the result of the first `<<` operator is the same object, against which the second, chained, `<<` operator will happily use.

Change all your `<<` operators to work this way.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thanks!